# The second shortest vectors of a lattice

Tags: geometry, reference-request, integer-lattices, discrete-geometry

When I read about famous lattices ($E_8$, Leech, ...) I always only see listed the norm of their shortest vectors. However, I am interested in the norm of the second shortest vectors (and if possible, also the norm of the $n$-shortest vectors).

I am not interested in computing these for arbitrary lattices, but I want to know of a reference that tabulates these norms for the most important lattices, or learn of a way to compute these norms from the other data usually given for such lattices.

Comment: The lattices you mentioned are integral lattices, so the norm of every vector is by definition an integer. The position of the nonzero coefficients of the lattice's [theta series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThetaSeries.html) describe which integers appear as norms of vectors in the lattice. I don't know of a standard reference, but many of these theta series can be found in the OEIS website (e.g. [E_8](http://oeis.org/A004009) and [Leech](http://oeis.org/A008408)).